# Is there any way to make an annotation in django, where I can make difference between timezone.now and other field?

Tags: python, sql, django

Is there any way I can do this in django?

```
  Notification.objects.filter(
    removable=Case(
        When(date_added__lte=timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=F('delete_after')), then=Value(1)),
        default=Value(0), output_field=IntegerField()
        ),
).delete()
```

Basically inside `When` I want to do this :

```
 date_added__lte=timezone.now() -datetime.timedelta(hours=F('delete_after')
```

Where `date_added` and `delete_after` belongs to the same table

Comment: What do you want to do? What's the goal?

Comment: I have different notifications, I have a celery worker which will delete old notifications. Some notifications can be deleted after 24 hours, other can be deleted after 1,2, or 3 months, depends on the importance. @makaveli

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track, something like this should work:

```
Notification.objects.annotate(
    removable=Case(When(date_added__lte=timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=F('delete_after')), then=Value(1)),
    default=Value(0), output_field=IntegerField())
).filter(removable=1).delete()
```